# From a specific date, on and after specific date

Tags: grammar

How to say in short "Files added on and after a specific date"? It refers to future, so I can not use "since" and I should omit "verb" added.
1. If I say , Files from a specific date, does it refer only to files added on that particular date? 
2. Can I say? Files from a specific date onwards? Any other suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Put a date "x" that falls before the real date and use "files added post x." it means all files that were added after x, which would include your real date and the future dates.

Comment: To me, "Files dated *from* [date]" would imply inclusion of the specified date, wheras "Files dated *after* [date] would imply exclusion of the specified date.  But to remove any ambiguity, use "Files dated *from* [date], inclusive".

Comment: @vickyace The prefix 'post' does not imply inclusiveness. If you were to look at the word 'postmodernism', it refers to a movement which occurred after the modernist movement.

Comment: @Michael Doesn't post x mean everything after x?

Comment: @vickyace Yes, but excluding X itself.

Comment: OP, 'Files from a specific date onwards' seems like a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: @Michael That is why I said to use the date just before the date that was to be included, so that post would include the intended date and those afterwards.

Comment: Why not use ≥ [date]?

Comment: @vickyace I guess I misunderstood. Still, I can't see what you're suggesting working well without sounding clunky. "Files added on 01/05/2015 and post-01/01/2015"? "Files added on and post-01/01/2015"? Both of these sound worse than if you avoided the word 'post', IMO.

Comment: I think a simple "Files added on **or** after **date**" covers it.

Comment: @Michael I meant "files added post 30/4/2015." That is less wordy and more pertinent.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Is there any way how to omit any verb (added, updated, deleted or dated..etc),as the verb will change depending on situation., If I say Files from a specific day onwards, or projects from a specific day onwards, does it sound ok to a native speaker?  This will be an option in a menu from where a user should select what files, projects etc. should be downloaded. In the next step, s/he will enter the date. Thank you.

Comment: @Lenka "files from x onwards" is also good or you can use "files post (date)."

Comment: @vickyace Then refer to my first comment. "files added post 30/4/2015" implies files added *on* 30/4/2015 are *not* okay.